# How to unit test this vue component with jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have this vue component and I would like to access its methods through my unit test file:

```
@Component
export default class Breadcrumb extends Vue {

  breadcrumbList: BreadcrumbData[] = [];

  mounted(): void {
    this.breadcrumbList = (this.$route.meta
      .breadcrumb as BreadcrumbData[]).concat({
      name: this.$route.name as string | undefined
    });
  }

  goTo(breadcrumb: BreadcrumbData) {
    if (breadcrumb.link) {
      this.$router.push(breadcrumb.link as RawLocation);
    }
  }
}
```

All the tutorials I find online use a different syntaxe to build the component with

```
export default {
    props: { ... },
    data: { ... },
    methods: {
        doSomeWork: function() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then access the methods through

```
const wrap = mount(DummyComp);
wrap.vm.doSomeWork();
```

but when I try the same with my syntaxe I get:
`Property 'goTo' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>'`

Can someone tell me how to access my component's methods?

Answer (score 0):

First you should define your functions inside the `methods` property. Also component scoped variables inside the `data` function.
Like this:

```js
export default class Breadcrumb extends Vue {
  data() {
     return {
       breadcrumbList: []
     }
  },
  mounted(): void {
     ...
  },
  methods: {
    goTo(breadcrumb: BreadcrumbData) {
      if (breadcrumb.link) {
        this.$router.push(breadcrumb.link as RawLocation);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods

Then you can reach them from tests too.